# Disable menu option for current page with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to disable the link to the current page in a drop down menu using preg_replace. Specifically, I'm attempting to append a class name and a "disabled" attribute to the menu option that points to the current page (the page name is in the query string).

So far I can load the menu, but my preg_replace doesn't do anything (preg_replace is too confusing for me at times).

```
<?php

$menu = file_get_contents("menu.php");
$q_param = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

$menu = preg_replace("|<option value=\"routemap.php?$q_param\"></option>|U", "<option value=\"routemap.php?$q_param\" class=\"red\" disabled=\"disabled\">$1</option>", $menu);

echo $menu;

?>
```

edit: fixed it with:

```
<?php
$menu = file_get_contents("menu.php");
$param = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$menu = preg_replace("/$param/", "$param\" class=\"red\" disabled=\"disabled", $menu);
echo $menu;
?>
```

It was a problem with beginning and end markers for the search pattern (I think).

Comment: Why not do it with CSS instead, with `display:none`? If that's an option for you. That's what I do.

Comment: Yea, @Fred has a point

Comment: `.hidden_items { display:none; }`